# How to create a ListBox within a ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

My project has a class I have created called `Column`, which consists of its name (`string`), its number (`int`) and a list of tasks (which is another class I have created).

I am trying to view these in a WPF window in a way that will show all the `Column`s in a list horizontally, with each item in the list having its own ListBox that will show the tasks it consists of vertically (basically a [kanban board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_board)). I have managed to make a horizontal `ListBox` for the column names but I encounter problems with creating the inner `ListBox`. How can I implememnt this?

My XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="ColList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Columns,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="SelectedColumn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="246" Margin="446,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=this.Tasks}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Remove this. from in front of tasks. And tell it how to template each task. In an itemtemplate. Path= is usually optional in a binding.

Comment: @Andy, Binding is a markup extension. It accepts Path as constructor parameter. In xaml any constructor parameter of markup extension can be written without `=`, as long as they come before other properties

Comment: You can write "{Binding Tasks}" or "{Binding Path=Tasks}" and both will work. You only really need Path= when you do more complicated binding. A binding with Path=this.Tasks is looking at Column for a property called "this" which is an object with a property Tasks. Tasks is a property of Column though.